# Do abilities that specify 'first' or 'single' attack apply to Cleave attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats, class-feature

Do abilities like [Furious Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/furious-focus-combat) (assuming Power Attack) or the [Two-Handed Fighter Overhand Chop](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/two-handed-fighter/) ability apply to [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleave-combat/), [Great Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/great-cleave-combat-final/), and/or [Cleaving Finish](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleaving-finish-combat/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Furious Focus and the Overhand Chop abilities function differently in this context.

---

## Furious Focus

Applies to the first attack roll in a round, regardless of where it's coming from (notably, because it doesn't depend on there only being one attack). So the initial attack from Cleave and associated feats wouldn't take the Power Attack penalty with Furious Focus.

---

## Overhand Chop

Only applies if you make exactly one attack with either the Attack action or a Charge, as specified in the text. Cleave and Great Cleave are not the Attack action, nor are they a charge, so they do not get to apply. However, you can use the Attack action to make an attack modified by Overhand Chop, and then get another attack from Cleaving Finish (though this extra attack doesn't get Overhand Chop's extra damage).

Answer (score 0):

Going purely by RAW, you cannot use abilities like Furious Focus and Two-Handed Fighter Overhand Chop with your additional attacks from Cleave et al. Any additional attacks from these abilities are a separate attack roll and therefore not your first attack.